# Magento2 Controller Override Not Working

Tags: magento2, controllers, di

I am trying to override product view controller and display a message on top by following this [tutorial](https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/how-to-override-controller-in-magento2/)

The message is not shown in product page and there is no error as well. Below are the code. Please advise.

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0" >
    <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
       </module>    
</config>
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
    <plugin name="company-custom" type="Company\Custom\Controller\Catalog\Product\View" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
</config>
```

View.php

```
namespace Company\Custom\Controller\Catalog\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Local controller";
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Message from new controller.');      
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you are not following the tutorial you mention. You are mixing preferences with plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In di.xml**

Instead of plugin ,*preference needs to be used*

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" type="Company\Custom\Controller\Catalog\Product\View" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**you are wrong step 3:**

Step:3 Overriding xml file
**File path: magento2\app\code\Jute\Customer\etc\di.xml**
[image]

```
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<config xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&#8221; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=”../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd”>
<preference for=”Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book” type=”Jute\Customer\Block\Address\Book” />
<preference for=”Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Index” type=”Jute\Customer\Controller\Address\Index” />
</config>
```